# Calling EmitVertex too many times results in failed compilation despite being under max_vertices count

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

In the main program, the maximum number of vertices that can be emitted by the geometry shader is queried:

```
GLint max_geo_out;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_GEOMETRY_OUTPUT_VERTICES, &max_geo_out);
printf("max vertices from geometry shader: %d\n", max_geo_out);
```

This shows me 1024 vertices.

A simple vertex shader is as follows:

```
#version 450 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0); 
}
```

Geometry shader:

```
#version 450 core

layout(points) in;

layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 1024) out;

out vec3 vertex_attribute;

void main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {    
        vertex_attribute = vec3(1, 1, 1);
        gl_Position = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);
        EmitVertex();
    }
    EndPrimitive();
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 450 core

in vec3 vertex_attribute;

out vec4 final_color;

void main()
{   
    final_color = vec4(vertex_attribute[0], 1, 1, 1);
}
```

These shaders fail to compile despite calling `EmitVertex()` 1024 times. Why is that?

Comment: Can you add the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: It results in a typical GL CALLBACK link error: type = 0x824C, severity = 0x9146.

Answer (score 1):

There are [two separate, independent limitations](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Geometry_Shader#Output_limitations) on the outputs of a geometry shader. Violating either of them leads to undefined behavior.

A GS must specify the maximum number of vertices that an invocation can emit as `max_vertices`. The implementations restricts the values it can accept for `max_vertices`, which can be queried via `GL_MAX_GEOMETRY_OUTPUT_VERTICES`. The OpenGL 4.6 specification requires that this value is *at least* 256. As such, `max_vertices` is allowed to be 1024... at least with regard to *this* limitation.

However, there is a second limitation: the amount of "stuff" a single GS invocation can emit.

"Stuff" here means components of vectors that all of your `out`-qualified variables consume. This includes *all outputs*, even the built-in ones like `gl_Position`. Because `gl_Position` is declared as a `vec4`, it consumes 4 components.

A GS invocation is not allowed to emit more total vertex components than this implementation-defined maximum. This second limitation is exposed by `GL_MAX_GEOMETRY_TOTAL_OUTPUT_COMPONENTS`, which must be at least 1024.

Note that these two limitations are *different*, and implementations do expose them differently.

For example, the [Radeon RX 6700 XT](http://opengl.gpuinfo.org/displayreport.php?id=11290) sets the max vertex count to 1023 but the maximum components to 4095.

This means that you set `max_vertices` to 1023, and still output 1023, so long as your number of components per-vertex is 4 or less. So you could write to *just* `gl_Position`. This is because 1023 * 4 is less than 4095.

By contrast, the [Geforce RTX 470](http://opengl.gpuinfo.org/displayreport.php?id=11312) only allows 1024 vertices with 1024 components. So the only way you can output 1024 vertices is if you only output 1 component per-vertex. If you want to write 4 component per-vertex (such as with `gl_Position`), you can only output 256 vertices.